# Javascript multiconverter

Tags: javascript

I have this 3 functions (multiconverter) in javascript, but i can´t figure it out why i can´t make the program to display the result.

```
function WhichConversion () {
    var answer = window.prompt( " Welcome to the Mutliconverter! What do you want to convert?  ( Dollars, Francs, Knots");
    if (answer == "Dollars", "Knots", "Francs"){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
function AskForValue () {
    var answer = window.prompt( " Enter a Value to Convert")
    return answer;
}
while (WhichConversion()) {
    var ConversionType = WhichConversion();
    var ConversionValue = AskForValue();
    var resultMessage = " The result is ";
    var result = 0;

    if (ConversionType == "Dollars"){
        resultMessage += DollarstoEuros(Number(ConversionValue))
        .toString();
    }else if (ConversionType == "Francs"){
        resultMessage += SwissFrancsToEuros(Number(ConversionValue))
        .toString();
    }else if (ConversionType == "Knots"){
        resultMessage += KnotstoKph(Number(ConversionValue))
        .toString();
    }else{
        resultMessage = " Pay attention! That conversion is not supported.";
    }
}
console.log(resultMessage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if statement to check for which conversion to use only has one check `answer == "Dollars"`. To make the script work for other values you will need to create multiple checks:

`if (answer == "Dollars" || answer == "Knots" || answer == "Francs"){`

For an working example check the code below:

```
var currentCurrency = '';

function WhichConversion () {
    var answer = window.prompt( " Welcome to the Mutliconverter! What do you want to convert?  ( Dollars, Francs, Knots");

    currentCurrency = answer;

    return answer !== null
}
function DollarstoEuros(value){
return value * 12;
}

function AskForValue () {
    var answer = window.prompt( " Enter a Value to Convert")
    return answer;
}

while (WhichConversion()) {
    var ConversionValue = AskForValue();
    var result = 0;
    var resultMessage = " The result is ";


    if (currentCurrency == "Dollars"){
        resultMessage += DollarstoEuros(Number(ConversionValue))
        .toString();
    }else if (currentCurrency == "Francs"){
        resultMessage += SwissFrancsToEuros(Number(ConversionValue))
        .toString();
    }else if (currentCurrency == "Knots"){
        resultMessage += KnotstoKph(Number(ConversionValue))
        .toString();
    }else{
        resultMessage = " Pay attention! That conversion is not supported.";
    }

 console.log(resultMessage);
}
```

Comment: MaartenDev thanks for help, it´s true that i assume the  == was for the 3 values, but one correct way is to put it in one array, thanks for that. However, as for the code, the problem continues, in order to get the result i need to cancel the pop up window and as for else condition inside the while loop it doesn´t show up the message

Comment: What is the expected behaviour of the prompt? Should it close after converting the first currency? And the output is printed to the console(check f12 in your browser). @Teixeira66

Comment: The expected behaviour is to display the convertion on the console(f12 or inspector on the menu of the browser) and in case we enter any other value, the message :"Pay attention.....", the programs continues until we cancel it.MaartenDev

Comment: Could you try the following example: https://jsfiddle.net/maartendev/5zd3mcoh/8/. Try entering: `Dollars` then `22` then `Invalid` then `cancel`. It should print every result to the console. @Teixeira66

Comment: MaartenDev brilliant, i was working on a similar solution, simplifying. i just deleted the function DollarstoEuros(value){
return value * 12;
} on my side, and it display properly on the browser. cheers

Comment: Nice good luck! Thanks for your clear answers and kindness :) @Teixeira66